# Getting errors with session variable in partialview MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-variables

Someone please help out: I added this statement to my partialview login page

```
@HttpContext.Current.Session["userID"] = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();
```

and receive errors below:

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term '='
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 66:             #line default
>   Line 67:             #line hidden
>   Line 68: EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 73, 37, false);
>   Line 69: 
>   Line 70:

Comment: Why are you even using Session here ? Can't you use `User.Identity.GetUserId`  wherever you want `Session["UserID"]` ?

Comment: And why is this code in the view, particularly a login view when the user does not even exist yet?

Answer (score 0):

As you try to perform assignments in Razor, it requires to wrap the code in curly brackers

```
@{ HttpContext.Current.Session["userID"] = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use User.Identity.GetUserId directly instead of session variable.

Thank you all.

Still, I appreciate it if someone can explain what that error means though.