# Invalid expression term =

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial

Guys I can't seem to figure out this one. I am kinda new to MVC and Razor so be gentle :D

I got this partial view:

```
@model Phonebook.PresentationLayer.Web.Models.EmailModel
@using Phonebook.BusinessLogicLayer.Managers;

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEmail", "EmailDetails", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Model.ParseIds= Model.Id + "/" + Model.Contact.Id;
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ParseIds)
    <div class="info-table add-email">
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "no-borders" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EmailAddress)
        </div>
        <div>
            @{
                EmailTypes emailTypesManager = new EmailTypes();
                IEnumerable<EmailTypeModel> emailTypes = emailTypesManager.GetAll().Select(x => (EmailTypeModel)x);
            }
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EmailType.Id, new     SelectList(emailTypes, "Id", "Name", Model.EmailType.Id), new { @class = "no-borders-drop" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EmailType.Name)
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">
        </div>

    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default add-email-button">Add new email</button>
}
```

Which I call with:

```
@Html.Partial("Partial/_EmailAdd", new EmailModel(){ Contact = Model.Contact})
```

But it keeps giving me this error which kinda does not make any sense to me:
[image]

Anyone have an idea where the problem might be?

Also since I'm new to the Razor I was wondering when do I NEED to use semicolon (";") in the View code?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you point out which line is #76? The error points to that line so it could narrow the problem down.

Comment: If you are using a viewmodel, then why are you constructing the Model.ParseIds in the view and not when you are populating the view model?  That line looks suspect to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I wrapped the line causing the error in @{} like so:

```
@{
 Model.ParseIds= Model.Id + "/" + Model.Contact.Id;
}
```

And the error changed to:

> Unexpected "{" after "@" character. Once inside the body of a code block (@if {}, @{}, etc.) you do not need to use "@{" to switch to code.

Simply by removing @ and {} leaving the line clear (since the line was already in the block of code) solved my problem.

Thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error caused by this assignment:

```
@Model.ParseIds= Model.Id + "/" + Model.Contact.Id;
```

Try to wrap the `Model` assignment inside Razor code block, or better to assign it inside controller action method instead:

```
@* View *@

@{
    Model.ParseIds = Model.Id + "/" + Model.Contact.Id;
}

// Controller

var model = new EmailModel();
// assign Id & Contact.Id here
model.ParseIds = model.Id + "/" + model.Contact.Id;

return PartialView("_EmailAdd", model);
```

`@Model.ParseIds` will output value of `ParseIds` as text in HTML, so that it's an invalid assignment when followed with `=` during parsing.

Similar issue:

[Getting errors with session variable in partialview MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803589/getting-errors-with-session-variable-in-partialview-mvc/34864649#34864649)